# MongoDB (Java driver) add element in a sub sub collection in one go

Tags: mongodb, collections, updates

I have a document that looks like this:

```
{
 "id":1,
 "layers": 
           [{
            "id" : 100,
            "files": [{
                       "id":1,
                       "name":"test"
                     }]
            }]
   }

@Document(collections="tests")
public class Test() {
   string id
   Set<..> layers;
}

public class Layers() {
 List<..> files;
}
```

Is it possible (given a documentId and and layerId) to add a new file object in one query ?
something like

```
db.test.update(
  { _id: 1 },
  { $push:
     {
       "layers.100.files": {"id":2,"name":"test2:}
     }
  }
)
```

when I try the above I get an error like:
cannot use the part (contentLayers ....) to traverse the element ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.test.update(
  { $and: [{_id: "1"}, {"layers.id": "100" }]},
  { $push:
     {
       "layers.$.files": 1
     }
  }
)
```

Here is the version non-java, the important point is having this $ before the array

Note there 'might' be an other way of doing this but the above works for me